# Angular 5 Invoking function in child element after it's loaded

Tags: angular, components, angular5, viewchild

I am trying to pass status from one component to another via third one.

Validation component -> View -> List

Validation component emits status. View on emit launches function that by ViewChild passes arguments to List and launch function there.

Problem is that List is rendering so long, that ViewChild upon emit is still undefined. I've checked ViewChild itself on AfterViewChecked and it takes couple of seconds to return the component. I also tried setTimeout(0) but no luck.

**Validation Component.ts**

```
this.onStatusChange.emit('success');
```

**View Component.html**

```
<validation-component
    (onStatusChange)="updateStatusIcon($event)">
</validation-component>
```

**View Component.ts**

```
import { ListComponent } from '../list/list.component'
...
@ViewChild(ListComponent) private listComponent;
...
    public updateStatusIcon(status): void {
            this.listComponent.setStatusIcon(status);
    }
```

Upon firing `updateStatusIcon()`, `this.listComponent` is still undefined.

Comment: Can you include how the `ListComponent` is getting included in the DOM?